# Facebook "xfbml.render" event for login button not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to add a loader to the Facebook login button described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/

To do this you need to listen on the `xfbml.render` event. Following their instructions I got this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=XXXX';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function () {
        console.log("finished rendering plugins");
    });
</script>

 <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="2" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="true"
     data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" data-scope="public_profile,email"
     onlogin="theChampAuthUserFB"></div>
```

However, when I run this I get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined
```

I then decided to adjust 2nd part of the script code like so:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        console.log("async");
        FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function() {
            console.log("finished rendering plugins");
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=XXXX';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div
    class="fb-login-button"
    data-max-rows="1"
    data-size="large"
    data-button-type="continue_with"
></div>
```

But the word "async" doesn't even run, regardless where I put the script tag.

Comment: can you edit your code so we actually see the current version?

Comment: @luschn question updated

Comment: what browser dev tools are you using? are you sure the console.log does not show up? even in chrome?

Comment: I'm testing this on chrome, so I'm not sure what's going on. Log level is on default. Please try it out yourself to see if you get the same issue

Comment: in jsfiddle, the console log entry shows up.  btw, you may want to read this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Have a look at the place I'm putting it: https://universityrevisionguru.co.uk/my-account/

It doesn't show up. Why now?

Comment: the login button does show up for me, in firefox and chrome. check if you have some plugin installed, or third party cookies deactivated, something like that.

Comment: I know the login button shows up. The issue is that the console.log('async') doesn't run.